# Loading javascript effect inside DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I found this effect and I'm trying to modify it to be loaded inside a DIV `myeffect`, for example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="myeffect"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried changing some variables but I'm not a JavaScript expert and I can't get it to work inside a DIC. The effect covers the whole screen from top to bottom.

The code is on Codepen and can be found here: https://codepen.io/emilykarp/pen/bVqxRm

Help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```js
var speeds = [];
var count = 1;
var colors = ['#bf1e2e', '#ee4037', '#dc5323', '#e1861b', '#e1921e', '#f7ac40', '#f7e930', '#d1da22', '#8bc43f', '#38b349', '#008d42', '#006738', '#29b473', '#00a69c', '#26a9e1', '#1a75bb', '#2a388f', '#262161', '#652d90', '#8e2792', '#9e1f64', '#d91c5c', '#ed297b', '#d91c5c', '#db1e5e', '#bf1e2e', '#f6931e', '#f05a28', '#f6931e', '#fbaf41']
var width = parseInt($('html').css('width'), 10);

var random = function(mult, add) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*mult) + add);
}; 

var drop = function(n, height, color) {
  $('.myeffect').append('<div class="drop" style="left:'+
                   n*15+'px;height:'+
                   height+'vh;background-color:'+
                   color+';"></div>');
};

var createDrops = function(space) {
  for (var i=speeds.length; i < space/10; i++) {
    speeds.push(random(3000, 2000));
    drop(i, random(70, 30), colors[count]);
    
    if (count < colors.length-1) { count++; }
    else { count = 0; }  
  }
};

var animateDrops = function(startingN) {
  for (var i=startingN; i<speeds.length; i++) { 
    $('.drop:nth-child('+i+')').slideDown(speeds[i]); 
  }
};

createDrops(width);
animateDrops(0);
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 16px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -4px -8px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -4px -8px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
  box-shadow: inset -4px -8px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myeffect" ></div>
```

Comment: Try giving `.myEffect` a width and height. You will see that the drips still fill the entire window. I'm pretty sure OP wants the drips to be rendered only within the div.

Comment: Exactly @Turnip, the idea is to have the effect loaded in a div below the website header and navigational menu with a height of 60% of the screen height. Webpage copy should continue below the effect. The above ain't really working. It shows an x-overflow for some reason and it's still outside of a DIV. I'm still working on it and hopefully will figure it out with your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could see you were missing 3 things in your codepen.

1. you were applying the change to 'html' not '.myeffect'

In your js:

```
`var width = parseInt($('.myeffect').css('width'), 10);`
```

2. you need to set a width to your '.myeffect'

In your css:

`.myeffect {
      width: 100px;
    }`

3. there was no markup in the 'HTML' section of codepen, outside of the html tag that codepen probably provides by default.

In your html:

```
  <html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div class="myeffect"></div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

My codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oegwZa

Answer (score 0):

The divs it uses are all dynamically generated and appended to the body using this method.

```
var drop = function(n, height, color) {
  $('body').append('<div class="drop" style="left:'+
                   n*15+'px;height:'+
                   height+'vh;background-color:'+
                   color+';"></div>')
    )};
```

So, you would just update the script to append to your element instead of the body element.

```
var drop = function(n, height, color) {
  $('.myeffect').append('<div class="drop" style="left:'+
                   n*15+'px;height:'+
                   height+'vh;background-color:'+
                   color+';"></div>')
    )};
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works for me now.

```
var speeds = [];
var count = 1;
var colors = ['#bf1e2e', '#ee4037', '#dc5323', '#e1861b', '#e1921e', 
'#f7ac40', '#f7e930', '#d1da22', '#8bc43f', '#38b349', '#008d42', '#006738', 
'#29b473', '#00a69c', '#26a9e1', '#1a75bb', '#2a388f', '#262161', '#652d90', 
'#8e2792', '#9e1f64', '#d91c5c', '#ed297b', '#d91c5c', '#db1e5e', '#bf1e2e', 
'#f6931e', '#f05a28', '#f6931e', '#fbaf41']
var width = parseInt($('.myeffect').css('width'), 10);

var random = function(mult, add) {
return Math.floor((Math.random()*mult) + add);
}; 

var drop = function(n, height, color) {
$('.myeffect').append('<div class="drop" style="left:'+
               n*60+'px;height:'+
               height+'vh;background-color:'+
               color+';"></div>');
};
var createDrops = function(space) {
 for (var i=speeds.length; i < space/60 + 2; i++) {
 speeds.push(random(3000, 2000));
 drop(i, random(35, 20), colors[count]);

if (count < colors.length-1) { count++; }
else { count = 0; }     
}
};

var animateDrops = function(startingN) {
 for (var i=startingN; i<speeds.length; i++) { 
  $('.drop:nth-child('+i+')').slideDown(speeds[i]); 
 }
};

createDrops(width);
animateDrops(0);
```